# How does chained methods execute in java?

Tags: java, methods, chaining

**Here is my code :**

```
result = method1().method2().method3();
```

I would  like to know the execution hierarchy of the above code/statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go through the following points.

1. Determine what the leftmost method call will return (let’s call it x).
2. Use x as the object invoking the second (from the left) method. If there
   are only two chained methods, the result of the second method call is
   the expression's result.
3. If there is a third method, the result of the second method call is used
   to invoke the third method.

As per your statement, the execution hierarchy will be as follows:

1. First , **method1()** which is the leftmost method will be called.
2. Suppose **method1()** returns an object "meth" then the second method (from the left) **method2()** will be called as meth.**method2()**.
3. Last, the object returned from **method2()** will be used to call the **method3()**.

Hope it clarifies you doubt.

Comment: Thank you for such a brief explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm explaining hierarchy of the above code with small example.

```
result = method1().method2().method3();
```

> Example:
>
> ```
> getYear().toString().trim(); //like method1().method2().method3()
> ```
>
> First will be execute get year() which returns a Integer:
>
> ```
> 2016.toString().trim();
> ```
>
> Secound will be execute toString() method of integer class which
>   returns an string:
>
> ```
> "2016".trim();
> ```
>
> In Last trimming the stringwith trim() method of string class.

Answer (score -1):

Same as this:

```
result1 = method1();
result2 = result1.method2();
result = result2.method3();
```