# What do you call the calling of multiple methods in a single line in java? In the below code we have methods manage(), window() and maximize()

Tags: java, selenium, oop

driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does chained methods execute in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35932711/how-does-chained-methods-execute-in-java)

Comment: I think this isn't a duplicate. I think he knows how it works, but he wants to know how such a construct is called (i.e. the specific term such a construct is designated with). Eventually he needs this to feed Google with the correct search keywords.

Answer (score 5):

That would be **Method Chaining**.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as method chaining, as stated in [Thibstars' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371606/6395627). In your case it's a more concise way of writing:

```
WebDriver driver = ...; // get instance from somewhere
WebDriver.Options options = driver.manage();
WebDriver.Window window = options.window();
window.maximize();
```

***Note:** The class types are assumed based on the [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) tag and method names.*

Answer (score 1):

Each call of the method usually returns the same object which has been calling it (like `return this`), allowing to call other methods on the same object. It can however return other objects which can also be method-chained or even void if it is a terminal method.

Comment: Method chaining does not require that `this` be returned.

Comment: I have said "like" as in "like, as example".  this is most commonly used, however other objects or even void (as terminal method call) is employed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not

Comment: Well, you wrote "Each call of the method returns the _same_ object which has been calling it" - that's actually not necessary. Methods could as well return different objects which might be used to "force" a certain "path" through the chain - e.g. in the OP's example `driver.manage()` will most likely return something different than the call to `.window()`.

Comment: I apologize if I'm reading your answer wrong. However, you saying "like" implies, in my opinion, that "`return this`" is an _example of how to implement_ the concept explained in the rest of your answer. The rest of your answer very clearly focuses on "[returning] the same object which has been calling it" which allows calls to "other methods on the same object". The point I was trying to make in my comment was that returning the same object _is not required_. The only important thing is that _an_ object of _any type_ is returned.